# Synchronising a medium sized sqlite database over several computers

Tags: rsync, sqlite

I have an SQLite database that is about 10MiB in size. Every few minutes a new record is inserted. Now I'd like to synchronise this file over several computers, with a remote server in between.

But the problem is: how do I do it without transferring the entire file over every few minutes?

I was thinking of something like rdiff, but maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: DropBox? Google Drive? SkyDrive? Box? For such a small file, what is your concern regarding transferring the entire file?

Comment: Because it would transfer the entire file every few minutes.